# How can I implement this model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, model, mongoose-schema

how can I implement this

```
[{
    "title": "pranam",
    "year": "2016",
    "rating": 9,
    "actors": [
        {
            "name": "Amir",
            "birthday": "16 Aug 1982",
            "country": "Bangladesh"
        },
        {
            "name": "Imran",
            "birthday": "15 Aug 1982",
            "country": "Bangladesh"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I had tried this ......

models/actors.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const actorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max:50
     },
    birthday:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    country:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }


 });
```

models/movies.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Joi = require('joi');
const actorSchema = require('../models/actors');


const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    min: 5,
    max: 50
},
year:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min:2,
    max:4
},
rating:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min:0,
    max:10
},
actors: {
    type: actorSchema,
    required: true
}

});
```

routes/movies.js

```
const { Movie, validate} = require('../models/movies');
const { Actor} = require('../models/actors');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', auth, async(req, res)=>{
    const movies = await Movie
    .find({}, { _id:0, __v:0 })
    res.send(movies);
 });  

router.post('/', async(req, res)=>{
   const {error} = validate(req.body);
   if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

 //May be problem is hare, But I can not solve 
 const actor = await Actor.findById(req.body.actorId);
 if(!actor) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Actors');



 let movie = new Movie({

     title: req.body.title,
     year: req.body.year,
     rating: req.body.rating,
     actors:[{
        name: actor.name,
        birthday: actor.birthday,
        country: actor.country
     }]   
 });


 try {
     movie = await movie.save();
     res.send(movie)
   } catch (ex) {
     console.log("Invalid Movie ");
   }
 });
module.exports =router;
```

I enter this by POST Method in postman
{ "title": "I hate love Story", "rating": "9", "actorId": [ "5d99ac95f17917117068631b", "5d99ad75c4edd61f98af740b"]
}
 this show only first actor data in movies output by GET  api call,
how can I show more actors data in movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of the question, every other thing looks fine until this point in routes/movies.js:

```
const actor = await Actor.findById(req.body.actorId);
```

I don't think that query is correct, firstly, [Model.findById()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) accepts just an id not an array of ids. Secondly, what you want to do here is to fetch all the actors as identified by the ids in the actorId array, this is a valid query for that:

```
const actors = await Actor.find(
  // Filter: fetch all actors whose Id is in the array of ids provided in the request
  { _id: { $in: req.body.actorId } }, 
  // Projection: Include just the name, birthday and country in the response, if any.
  { name: 1, birthday: 1, country: 1 } 
);
```

You can check [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) for more info on how to use its query interface.
The query up there should return multiple actors and that is what you need, you can then, instantiate a new movie model with that:

```
 new Movie({
   title: req.body.title,
   year: req.body.year,
   rating: req.body.rating,
   actors,
 });
```

Comment: You are welcome. One more thing though, I think it's important that I point out the fact that the way the actors data is stored in the movies object is not *normalized*, for example, if for one reason or the other you need to update an actor name, you might need to update it in both the Actors and Movies collection, which I think would be a pain, anyways, this depends on your implementation.